# Casting NSManagedObject to subclass returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, restkit

When I try to cast an NSManagedObject to my model class (SCUser) while using RestKit 0.23.0 in Swift, the return value is nil. Here's the operation:

```
var urlString:String = SCApi.sharedInstance.apiUrl + "users/find_or_create?name=\(name)&email=\(email)"
var url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

var responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: SCUser.entityMapping(), method: RKRequestMethod.Any, pathPattern: nil, keyPath: "user", statusCodes: nil)

var operation = RKManagedObjectRequestOperation(request: request, responseDescriptors: [responseDescriptor])
operation.managedObjectContext = RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore().mainQueueManagedObjectContext
operation.managedObjectCache = RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore().managedObjectCache

operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(
    {
        (operation:RKObjectRequestOperation!, result:RKMappingResult!) -> Void in

        println("result: \(result.firstObject())")
        var object:NSManagedObject = result.firstObject() as NSManagedObject
        if let user = (object as? SCUser) {
            println("success: \(user)")
        } else {
            println("failure")
        }
    },
    failure: {
        (operation:RKObjectRequestOperation!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        println("error: \(error)")
    }
)
operation.start()
```

When this runs, it indicates that `result.firstObject()` is an SCUser, but doesn't cast it as one:

```
result: <NSManagedObject: 0x1740aee20> (entity: SCUser; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://7CFB18B0-0E2D-4190-B8DF-20470425CFE3/SCUser/p5> ; data: {
    authenticationToken = Dt7tjbLtUzSAgBdzCyC3;
    name = g;
    email = "foo@gmail.com";
    userId = "9e99451d-ef9d-4876-bfd3-4a987c2fe316";
})
failure
```

I've put the SCUser class and RestKit initialization [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aa9f102793779dbf7597), in case that's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This log output

```
result: <NSManagedObject: 0x1740aee20> (entity: SCUser; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://7CFB18B0-0E2D-4190-B8DF-20470425CFE3/SCUser/p5> ; data: {
    authenticationToken = Dt7tjbLtUzSAgBdzCyC3;
    name = g;
    email = "foo@gmail.com";
    userId = "9e99451d-ef9d-4876-bfd3-4a987c2fe316";
})
```

shows that the class is actually `NSManagedObject`, even though the entity is `SCUser`. Most likely this is because you haven't set the class name in your model, and presumably you have manually generated the `SCUser` class code files? You need to set the class name (and preferably auto-generate the class files, either with Xcode or mogenerator).